# Memory Leak caused by Accessing Undefined Array Index

Tags: php, arrays, memory

I am having a script which analyses XML data and fills same arrays with information.

For some (huge) input, the script crashed.

There is a foreach loop which is run around 180 times without problems (memory_get_usage() in iteration 180 around 20 MB, each loop adds around 0.1 MB)

Then it happens that with each new loop, the memory usage just doubles.

With the use of lots of logging I was able to track the problem down to the following line in a foreach.

$fu = $f['unit']

`$f` has the following structure:

```
array (
  'name' => 'Test',
  'value' => '4',
  'unit' => 'min-1',
)
```

But in some (many) cases (but also before the 180th iteration), the key `unit` was not existing in the array.

I was able to eliminate the problem by replacing the line with:

```
$fu = (isset($f['unit']) ? $f['unit'] : '');
```

Then the iteration runs until finished (totally 370 iterations).

Is there any explanation for the phenomena?

PHP version: PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10 with Suhosin-Patch (old...)

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: if you've found a memory leak in a supported version of PHP, then you should report it on the PHP bug tracker. However, your solution using `isset()` is the correct one -- this is considered best practice when accessing an array element that may not exist in any case.

Comment: @Spudley: edited - I just wanted to make sure if this is something known or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem might come from the PHP error handler and not from your actual loop.

like you said, not every "unit" key is existing and will therefore rise an error (or Exception depending on your error handlers). This might also include a stack trace and further debugging information depending on what extensions (xdebug?) you installed.

Both will consume memory.

It's allways a good practice to check for variables existance before using it. Allways enable E_NOTICE errors in your development system to see any such problems.